# Cannot use import statement outside a module in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, package.json

Why I am enable to add chart.js in my html getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

here my project structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omzhs.png)

and here my package.json file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r19M6.png)

I also add type module in package.json file

Comment: Rather than the screenshot of code, add the actual code, and the actual error message too